# Laravel mix 4 production build throw error at 92%

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

my project built and run pretty well on local machine with production environment but when i deploy it to server and run "npm run production", it stuck at 92% then throw an error:

```
Executing pre-build scripts
92% chunk asset optimization TerserPluginnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-29T10_50_55_510Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ prod: npm run production
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-29T10_50_55_538Z-debug.log
```

This is my webpack.mix.js:

```
const  mix  = require('laravel-mix');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
const FontminPlugin = require('fontmin-webpack');

mix.options({
  terser: {
    sourceMap: true,
    parallel: true,
  },
});

mix.sourceMaps().webpackConfig({devtool: 'source-map'});

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  mix.version();
}

mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9]\.[a-z0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
});

mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    new FontminPlugin({
      autodetect: true
    }),
    new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildStart:['php artisan lang:js public/js/message.js --quiet'], onBuildEnd:['php artisan laroute:generate --quiet']}),
  ]
});

mix.sass('resources/assets/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css').options({
      postCss: [
        require('autoprefixer')()
      ]
    }).react([
        'resources/assets/js/app.js'
    ], 'public/js/app.js');

mix.extract();
```

My node version: 10.16, my npm version: 6.9.0. I tried to change parallel: true from terser to false but still get the same error. "npm run dev" works well with my server so this is probably development build problem

Comment: Did you check your local and server node and NPM versions?

Comment: Yes, it is the same with my local machine: node version: 10.16, my npm version: 6.9.0

Comment: Try to comment/uncomment yout webpackConfigs

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. Have you found a solution?